# How to do a loop to check all the variables at the same time for C#?

Tags: c#

I want to loop all blueBallPosition[i] and greenBallPosition[i] except blueBallPosition[0] and greenBallPosition[0]. And also, I want to do an if else statement if all the variables except [0], are > 360. Whereas, [0] are < 360. I have tried to do a loop. However, if blueBallPosition[1] > 360 and greenBallPosition[1] > 360, pause will be set to true already. I want to loop through all the variables to make sure they are > 360, then pause set to true.

```
for (int i = 1; i < levelBall; i++)
{
    if ((blueBallPosition[0]  < 360) && 
        (greenBallPosition[0] < 360) && 
        (blueBallPosition[i]  > 360) && 
        (greenBallPosition[i] > 360))
            {
                pause = true;
            }
}
```

For your information, levelBall is set as 4.

I have solved it. I just have to add a counter to it.

```
for (int i = 1; i < levelBall; i++)
        {
            if ((blueBallPosition[0] < 360) && (greenBallPosition[0] < 360) && (blueBallPosition[i] > 360) && (greenBallPosition[i] > 360))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count == (levelBall))
        {
            pause = true;
        }
        else
        {
            count = 0;
        }
```

Comment: Search for a condition not met, set pause to false and leave the loop (to gain time).

Answer (score 2):

So you only want to pause if all balls (apart from 0) are > 360?

```
bool pause = false;

// Check ball[0] outside the loop for performance.
if (blueBallPosition[0] < 360 && greenBallPosition[0] < 360)
{
    pause = true;
    for (int i = 1; i < levelBall; i++)
    {
        if (blueBallPosition[i]  <= 360) || (greenBallPosition[i] <= 360))
        {
            pause = false;
            // You have found a ball that doesn't match, so no need
            // to keep checking.
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to check if all the variables fulfill that condition you can't set it to true if one fulfills them, you can rewrite it to start as true, check if one of them does not fulfill it and then set it to false instead. If it still true afterwards you know what all the variables fulfill the condition.

```
pause = true;
for(...) 
    if(blue[0] >= 360) || green[0] >= 360 || blue[i] <= 360 || green[i] <= 360)
         pause = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (blueBallPosition[0] < 360 &&
    greenBallPosition[0] < 360 &&
    blueBallPosition.Skip(1).All(b => b > 360) &&
    greenBallPosition.Skip(1).All(b => b > 360))
    pause = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

you may try use linq to make it more readable:

```
        if (blueBallPosition[0] < 360 && greenBallPosition[0] < 360)
        {
            var paulse = blueBallPosition.Select((b, idx) =>
                new { Blue = b, Green = greenBallPosition[idx] })
             .Skip(1).All(x => x.Blue > 360 && x.Green > 360);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pause = true;

for (int i = 1; i < levelBall; i++)
{
    if ((blueBallPosition[0]  >= 360) || 
        (greenBallPosition[0] >= 360) || 
        (blueBallPosition[i]  <= 360) || 
        (greenBallPosition[i] <= 360))
            {
                pause = false;
                break;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, move the checks that you can outside of the loop. Then assume that all checks pass and then undo that assumption if it turns out to be false:

```
if ((blueBallPosition[0]  < 360) && 
    (greenBallPosition[0] < 360))
{
    pause = true;
    for (int i = 1; i < levelBall; i++)
    {
        if((blueBallPosition[i]  <= 360) || 
        (greenBallPosition[i] <= 360))
        { 
            pause = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

very short code just like:

```
  var pause = false;
  if (blueBallPosition[0] < 360 && greenBallPosition[0] < 360)
  {
    pause = blueBallPosition.Any(b => b <= 360) || greenBallPosition.Any(b => b < 360);
  }
```

Do not forget the using in namespace.
  using System.Linq;

Answer (score 0):

Alex and Rex the bad thing on your code u are using ALL = all means loop all elements if you modify your solution with Any will be better.